# '[Double?]' is not convertible to '[Double]'

Tags: ios, swift, casting, option-type

maybe question is so silly but i am new in iOS
how can I convert optional to non-optional data array

> [Double?] is not convertible to [Double]

Here is line with error

```
   let massive = [dictionary[j]![one]?.doubleValue] as [Double]
```

I am converting to [Double] because i am using it here

```
let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(values: massive, xIndex: c)
```

And it throws error

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'BarChartDataEntry' with an
>   argument list of type '(values: [Double?], xIndex: Int)'

contructor of class BarChartDataEntry is like that

```
public init(values: [Double], xIndex: Int)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the relevant code.

Comment: What do you want to do about the elements of the `[Double?]` array that are nil? Drop them? Replace them with NaN or zero?

Comment: @Arc676 thanks, edited

Comment: I see, you're using ios-charts, you may need to re-evaluate your datasource, it can be done without optionals... or you can always run flatMap on your [Double?]. See my answer for an example.

Comment: try dictionary[j]?[one]?.doubleValue ?? 0

Comment: @LeoDabus your suggestion not helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Double?] is wrapped, you have to unwrap it in order to use it as a [Double]. To better understand, take a look at what your Doubles are wrapped with:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case None // has no value
    case Some(T) // has some value 
}
```

So you need to unwrap your optionals in order to use them as non-optional [Double].

One option, is that you can perform a `flatMap` operation on your optional array which will convert your [Double?] to a [Double]. Bear in mind that flatMap will copy your array and replace it, so if you're performing a flatMap on a very large array you might run into issues.

Here's a playground ready example:

```
var dubs : [Double?] = [1.2,1.4]

print(dubs) // [{Some 1.2}, {Some 1.4}]

var newDubs = dubs.flatMap { dub in
    return dub
}

print(newDubs) // [1.2, 1.4]
```

Comment: not a problem, you should evaluate what @Leo Dabus suggested in the comments as well, he's a very high rep user and his advice is usually spot on.

Comment: but this code dictionary[j]?[one]?.doubleValue not helped me, error still occurs

Comment: if my solution works for you just go with it. I was just suggesting that you take a look at Leo Dabus's comment and see if it works. Good luck with your charts

Comment: Or even shorter: `let foo = dubs.flatMap { $0 }`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your value for your double is. In this case, you must be sure that it has a decimal point, and is not 0.0. In which case, you can put your code as

```
//your code
... = Double[...]
```

It should resolve. Else, please provide some code so I can suggest a way to resolve. Hope this works for you :)

Comment: [dictionary[j]![one] is type of NSDecimalNumber, i converted to double because functions i wanted to call was type of [Double]. whatever thank you man for you try